# While installing sitecore jss with next.js

Tags: next.js, sitecore

When I am running the command`jss deploy app -c -d`, I am getting the error below,

```
PS C:\development\next-jss-prj\nextjs> jss deploy app -c -d
JSS is creating a manifest for sitecore-jss-app to ./sitecore/manifest...
Error generating manifest Error: Unable to load manifest require C:\development\next-jss-prj\nextjs\sitecore\definitions\config.js: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\development\next-jss-prj\nextjs\sitecore\definitions\config.js'
Require stack:
- C:\development\next-jss-prj\nextjs\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-dev-tools\dist\cjs\manifest\generator\generate.js
- C:\development\next-jss-prj\nextjs\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-dev-tools\dist\cjs\manifest\index.js
- C:\development\next-jss-prj\nextjs\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-dev-tools\dist\cjs\disconnected-server\create-default-disconnected-server.js
- C:\development\next-jss-prj\nextjs\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-dev-tools\dist\cjs\index.js
- C:\development\next-jss-prj\nextjs\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-cli\dist\cjs\scripts\clean.js
- C:\development\next-jss-prj\nextjs\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-cli\dist\cjs\scripts\index.js
- C:\development\next-jss-prj\nextjs\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-cli\dist\cjs\cli.js
- C:\Users\rholenna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-cli\dist\cjs\bin\jss.js
    at initRequire (C:\development\next-jss-prj\nextjs\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-dev-tools\dist\cjs\manifest\generator\generate.js:92:15)
    at C:\development\next-jss-prj\nextjs\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-dev-tools\dist\cjs\manifest\generator\generate.js:161:9
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\development\next-jss-prj\nextjs\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-dev-tools\dist\cjs\manifest\generator\generate.js:31:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\development\next-jss-prj\nextjs\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-dev-tools\dist\cjs\manifest\generator\generate.js:27:12)
    at generateToVariable (C:\development\next-jss-prj\nextjs\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-dev-tools\dist\cjs\manifest\generator\generate.js:160:12)
    at C:\development\next-jss-prj\nextjs\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-dev-tools\dist\cjs\manifest\generator\generate.js:189:38
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\development\next-jss-prj\nextjs\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-dev-tools\dist\cjs\manifest\generator\generate.js:31:71
PS C:\development\next-jss-prj\nextjs>
```

I am trying to run  the command `jss deploy app -c -d` in power shell and expecting after deploying app to see the changes inside Sitecore. I am using `next.js` and `sitecore 10.3 version`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.